# Infinite scrolling carousel "flashing image" bug with React JS

Tags: reactjs, image, css-animations, carousel

I'm working on an infinitely scrolling carousel. The Track element contains all Card elements. A css animation tweens the Track element forwards by the length of one Card element before resetting.

On each animation iteration, the last Card in the track is moved to the beginning and the Component is re-rendered.

The **problem** I'm experiencing is at the end of each animation iteration, all of the cards in the track *may* flash a different image. This occurs at least 80% of the time. You can preview it here [here.](https://minorities-mint.vercel.app/#art)

I'm wondering what's causing this behavior exactly, and what the solution is. The working theory is either React or the img element is rendering asynchronously, and so the animation is completing and resetting a frame before the images are re-rendered.

I tried to solve it by changing the img attributes for each image from the DOM nodes and got the same behavior so maybe it isn't React? [I made a Codepen](https://codepen.io/cryptominnow/pen/GRvYaXM) that doesn't uses vanilla JS and no img element and works just fine.

```
const Card = props => {
  return (
    <div {...props}>
      <img src={props.src} />
    </div>
  );
}

//  Returns an array of JSX elements representing cards in the carousel.
const makeCards = (num, images) => {
  return Array(num)
    .fill(null)
    .map((__, index) => {
      return <Card src={images[index]} key={index} />;
    });
};

export default (props) => {

  const trackRef = useRef();

  //Populate the cards array
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(() => makeCards(12, props.images));

  useEffect(() => {
    trackRef.current?.addEventListener(
      "animationiteration",
      onAnimationIteration
    );
  }, []);

  //move last card to beginning of array and trigger re-render
  const onAnimationIteration = () => {
    cards.unshift(cards.pop())
    setCards([...cards]);
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Track ref={trackRef} animSpeed={props.animSpeed}>
        {cards}
      </Track>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your app and it's working fine on my PC. Try opening it in a different system or browser. These things can change from browser to browser.

Comment: I’m using chrome. I’ll try a different browser but everyone else I share the app with also see the flashing bug

Comment: I tried opening the app in Chrome/Firefox and came across the flashing bug just once and the array was working fine then too. Maybe you should check this on a sufficiently powerful computer.

Comment: I tried firefox and I don't experience the flashing bug. Whatever the case I can't expect people to be using one browser over another so the problem still stands